# How do I implement last resort error handling in PHP CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, error-handling

In web frameworks I've built and used in the past, there's been some means to specify some form of "last resort" error handler. I'd appreciate any help in determining how to accomplish that goal using CodeIgniter, which is a legacy part of a product I'm working on.

The goal of the last resort error handler is to capture any exception that's bubbled up, unhandled, from the application logic. Since, at this high framework level, the handler can't resolve the exception, a typical implementation is to log the error (with associated context) and present a user-friendly error page rather than a scary, technical exception page.

I wasn't able to find support in the CodeIgniter documentation, but I expect there must be support for this. Did I not find support because I should use PHP's [set_error_handler()](http://us.php.net/set_error_handler) and [set_exception_handler()](http://us.php.net/set_exception_handler)? (I'm new to PHP, but expert in Java, Ruby/Rails.)

Thanks in advance for you guidance!

Comment: Do you want to catch exceptions or do you just want good error logging with friendly error pages?  You say you want an error handler that doesn't handle errors, so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: The last resort error handler would catch exceptions not handled by application code. Since it's at a high level, the only thing it can do is log the error and present a friendly error page to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems CodeIgniter 2.0+ registers the handlers you specified to load the CI_Exceptions class.  I usually put a MY_Exceptions library in the application/libraries folder to "catch" them before CodeIgniter.  I'd rather handle them gracefully than let CI show it's error pages.